# Working with matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Considering the 3x3 matrix:

```
m = {{0, -(I/Sqrt[2]), 0}, {I/Sqrt[2], 0, -(I/Sqrt[2])}, {0, I/Sqrt[2], 0}}
```

How would I find its normalized vectors eigenvectors u_i and construct the matrix U with column vectors u_i? I tried using `Noralize[Eigeinvectors[m]]` but it threw an error so I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Try `Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[m]` instead. To get the matrix where the columns are the normalized eigenvectors, do `Normalize /@ Eigenvectors[m] // Transpose`.

Comment: `Eigenvectors@N@m` also gives normalized eigenvectors, but they are numeric of course